# How to add a tooltip to a <option> in a <select> box in HTML?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

In firefox stable (v38) and earlier versions of chrome, I have used the "title" HTML attribute on  nodes so that the user can hover over a given option and view a tooltip or "hover text".  Here's an example of what I am referring to:

```
<select>
    <option title="hover text!">Thing 1</option>
    <option title="hover text!">Thing 5</option>
    <option title="hover text!">Thing 3</option>
    <option title="hover text!">Thing 2</option>
    <option title="hover text!">Thing 42</option>
</select>
```

Here is a jsfiddle of the above code:  http://jsfiddle.net/lsabota/bt3x780j/20/

This seems to work with firefox stable (v38), but doesn't work with the latest stable version of Chrome and doesn't seem to work with Firefox Aurora.  I would expect a user to be able to hover over any of the options and see the title text (which works in older version of Chrome and the latest version of Firefox). I had always thought that the title HTML attribute was the proper way to do this - is there another way to accomplish this?  Is the title attribute getting deprecated for  nodes?

Comment: Working for me in Chrome 43.0.2357.8

Comment: I'm on chrome 45 and it's working. you just have to hover over it for a second

Comment: Also working for me in Firefox 39 (Aurora)

Comment: Not working on: Google Chrome: 43.0.2357.81 m; Firefox: 38.0.1 or Opera: 29.0.1795.60

Comment: I wonder if this is perhaps platform specific?  I've noticed it on both Linux (RHEL6) and Windows 7 for Firefox 38.0.1, Linux with firefox-aurora, and Windows with Chrome 43.0.2357.81m.  What OS are you all running?

Comment: I opened a bug on the mozilla bugzilla and this has been resolved in firefox.  "Title" is a valid attribute for option and is respected among major browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a bug on the mozilla bugzilla and this has been resolved in firefox. "Title" is a valid attribute for option and is respected among major browsers

Answer (score 0):

After doing some Google and research I came to know the mentioned latest version of web browser does not work with title attribute. The Title attribute does not deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the comment; would you mind sharing any of the links where you found this information?